# llvmipa.lib not available for llvm Kaleidoscope (llvm 4.0)

Tags: visual-studio, llvm

I configured llvm with VS 2015 but built it with VS 2017. I am now trying the Kaleidoscope example using VS 2017. After a few trial and errors I was able to link most of the libraries. However when trying chapter 2, the build was trying to look for llvmipa.lib at the llvm build tree, and it does not exist. I tried to search the source tree and didn't find it there either.

Can anyone give me some hints how to resolve this issue? Is there a workaround? I have some general ideas of the purposes of llvmipa, but do not have any detailed knowledge about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the macro "add_kaleidoscope_chapter". This is a macro referring to other macros, which I later added to the CMakeLists and the it worked.